# convert string to datetime format invalid System.Datetime

Tags: c#

I have been trying many different solutions found here but none works. I want to convert the string to the format of dd/MM/yyyy

```
editField["ExpiryTime"] = "5/19/2011 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(editField["ExpiryTime"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I always get an error of invalid System.DateTime. Pleaes help!

Comment: hint: I'm pretty sure `19` is not a month.

Comment: @Rotem ExpiryTime is in format M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM|PM

Comment: Right, will edit it. But what I want to do is convert it to the format dd/MM/yyyy. SO how can I achieve this? thanks~

Answer (score 2):

Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to avoid culture issues like invalid date separators and this format:

```
M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
```

Uppercase `M` is for months, `dd` are the days, `yyyy` the four digit years. Lowercase `hh` are the hours in 12h format(required in combination with AM/PM), `mm` are the minutes, `ss` the seconds and `tt` the AM/PM designator.

```
string input = editField["ExpiryTime"].ToString(); // "5/19/2011 12:00:00 AM"
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> I want to convert the string to the format of dd/MM/yyyy

Then use `ToString` in the same way, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` forces `/` as date separator, without it will be replaced with your current culture's date-separator:

```
string result = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it as string, then you should try this

```
var dt = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",DateTime.Now);
```

Note: Also check your local system date time format. If it mismatches with the used one , still you might experience the same exception..